# How to create for Dbus Mainloop for two separate Dbus Python programs

Tags: python, python-3.x, dbus, pybluez, networkmanager

I have a python processes that monitor and interact with a Dbus service (NetworkManager)

Currently this runs in it's own thread from the main program

```
import dbus.mainloop.glib
import NetworkManager

PYTHON3 = sys.version_info >= (3, 0)
if PYTHON3:
    from gi.repository import GObject as gobject
    from gi.repository import GLib as glib
else:
    import gobject

class NetworkController(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, run_daemon_mode=False):
        # Set up DBus loop
        self.loop = None
        dbus.mainloop.glib.threads_init()
        dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
        
        if PYTHON3:
            self.loop = glib.MainLoop()
        else:
            self.loop = gobject.MainLoop()
            gobject.threads_init()

        #Create the thread
        super(NetworkController, self).__init__(daemon=run_daemon_mode)

    def run(self):
        """
        Method to run the DBus main loop (on a thread)
        """

        # NetworkManager init stuff...
        
        logger.debug("Starting Network Controller loop.")
        self.loop.run()
        logger.debug("Network Controller loop has exited.")

def main(argv):
    
    args=cli(argv) 

    #create network controller object but don't start the thread
    network_con = network_controller.NetworkController(True)
    network_con.start()     #

    try:
        while True:
```

I now need to add in a thread to control my bluetooth GATT service (pyBluez implementation) that also uses Dbus. How do I structure my code to let each process run in it's own thread and use Dbus.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created my new class which uses Dbus and is a separate thread the same way I created my first class.  Then from my main routine I called the class constructor and start each thread.

```
class AnotherGlibMainloop(threading.Thread):

def __init__(self, run_daemon_mode=False):
    # Set up DBus loop
    self.loop = None
    dbus.mainloop.glib.threads_init()
    dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
    
    if PYTHON3:
        self.loop = glib.MainLoop()
    else:
        self.loop = gobject.MainLoop()
        gobject.threads_init()

    #Create the thread
    super(NetworkController, self).__init__(daemon=run_daemon_mode)

def run(self):
    """
    Method to run the DBus main loop (on a thread)
    """

    # NetworkManager init stuff...
    
    logger.debug("Starting Another Glib Mainloop.")
    self.loop.run()
    logger.debug("Another Glib Mainloop has exited.")

def main(argv):    args=cli(argv) 

#create network controller object but don't start the thread
network_con = network_controller.NetworkController(True)
network_con.start()     #

another_glib_mainloop = AnotherGlibMainloop(True)
another_glib_mainloop.start()

try:
    while True:
```